# The npm version stays unchanged when I switch node version with the n library

Tags: node.js, npm

I want my npm version to match my node version but no matter what node version I change it to with the n library the npm version is always 9.5.1 on my mac.

```
> node -v
v16.14.0
> npm -v
9.5.1
> which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
> ls -l /usr/local/bin/npm
lrwxr-xr-x  1 yonghe  admin  38 11 27 23:00 /usr/local/bin/npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

Change node version to v10.24.1 and npm version still is v9.5.1

```
> node -v
v10.24.1
> npm -v
ERROR: npm v9.5.1 is known not to run on Node.js v10.24.1. You'll need to upgrade
to a newer Node.js version in order to use this version of npm. This version of
npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0`. You
can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
```

Comment: See: https://github.com/tj/n/issues/484